# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, sharepoint

This is the code which I used.
And I have added Microsoft.SharePoint.dll .

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

    class
    {          
      SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl);
    }
```

The Error shows like this
:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. 
 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Is it that version of the Sharepoint Dll you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Check references in your project. Is there a Microsoft.SharePoint reference?

2) If there is a reference and it's not corrupted, check the version by opening library properties.

2.1) If you have referenced a newer version, add an assembly binding with bindingRedirect in app config, for example:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

3) Enable the Fusion log [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) and read the logs.

Comment: Is it must to keep this file in in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll